# NavigationDrawer: no more animation on drawer icon when setting drawer listener

Tags: android, animation, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

[image: Drawer icon]  <-- the drawer icon

If you create, with android studio, a project with a navigation drawer, when you open/close the drawer, there will be a smooth animation of the drawer icon.

If I add a drawer listener to my drawerlayout, there is no more animation the drawer icon doesnt change anymore:

```
DrawerLayout dl = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    dl.setDrawerListener(new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl,R.drawable.ic_drawer,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close));
```

I tried to override methods of ActionBarDrawerToggle to add calls to syncState().

```
   DrawerLayout dl = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
            super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    };
    dl.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Now, when the drawer is open, I have a small icon, and then it switch to a large icon when the drawer is closed, but I dont have the smooth animation.

Does somebody know how to get the smooth animation?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the `@Override` annotations that are missing for the last two listeners and remove all `syncState()` calls. Call syncState() from your Activity's `onPostCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Comment: I just tried, it doesn't change the behavior: no animation.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem.It's been a long time since the question was asked, but if you are still interested, here is my answer.

put

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

instead of

```
syncstate();
```

for onDrawerClosed(), onDrawerOpened(), onDrawerSlide(), onDrawerStateChanged()

Also, put

```
@Override

protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intilize the boolean as false..`private boolean isDrawerOpen = false;`

```
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            if(slideOffset > .55 && !isDrawerOpen){
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 1);
                onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                isDrawerOpen = true;
            } else if(slideOffset < .45 && isDrawerOpen) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView,slideOffset);
                onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                isDrawerOpen = false;
            }
        }

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("Your title");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("your title");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesnt solve my probleme:I dont have the smooth animation (I just see the open drawer icon then the closed drawer icon, not the animation).